# The path to docker's volumes in Ubuntu

Tags: server, docker

I'm both new to Ubuntu and Docker. I cut to the chase, when I create a volume using the `sudo docker volume create TEST` command, where should I expect to find the `TEST` volume and its data in my hard drive?

If I want it to be located in another drive, lets say `D:\` (still new to ubuntu not sure if it also applies to linux) drive, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like it is /var/lib/docker/volumes

Here's what I got:

```
$ docker volume create TEST 
$ ls /var/lib/docker/volumes
metadata.db  TEST/
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `docker volume inspect TEST` ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_inspect/)), and there will be a key "Mountpoint" with the path to it:

```
$ docker volume inspect TEST
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-09-18T10:46:55-07:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/TEST/_data",
        "Name": "TEST",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

To extract just the path, for example to use in a script:

```
$ docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' TEST
/var/lib/docker/volumes/TEST/_data
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an old question, I already solved it a long long time ago back in the day I was new to docker. But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu installations that use snap for installing docker the path is:

`/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/`

For 20.04 LTS snap is default.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on WSL2 through Docker Desktop for Windows, volumes will be found here:

`/var/data/docker-desktop/default/daemon-data`

If you are working on actual Ubuntu, then yes, as the above answer said it will be located in

`/var/lib/docker/volumes`