# Will doing a full backup of my Ubuntu server backup the docker containers too?

Tags: server, backup, docker

I've been searching for the best way to basically take a 'snapshot' of a ubuntu server and store it separately to make a system-wide backup of my system. And it was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system) My questions are:

- Will it backup the docker containers/volumes with it e.g. will it backup the drive which holds my nextcloud files
- Are there better solutions when it comes to backing up everything so that if something did go wrong, I could just revert back to a backup.

So is there a feature like Time Machine for Ubuntu that could be reliable and fully automated (a backup once a day).

I use Backblaze for both my PC and my Mac, and I'm still trying to find something like.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the full question, but to cover the first half at least.

> Will it backup the docker containers/volumes with it e.g. will it backup the drive which holds my nextcloud files

Yes it will, you just have to make sure the directory that contains the Docker volumes are preserved. (Usually `/var/lib/docker/volumes`)

See this question for more info:
[The path to docker's volumes in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043661/the-path-to-dockers-volumes-in-ubuntu)